# changing git branch base gone wrong

Tags: git

I have a tree like this:

```
commit10 - commit11  <-- master
              |
              |-- commit3 <-- topic/branch1
                     |
                     |-- commit4 <-- topic/branch2
```

The git log looked like this:

```
$ git log -n 4
commit4
commit3
commit11
commit10
```

While I was working on commit4, commit3 was merged to master and was farther back in the history, so I wanted to change the branch base for topic/branch2 to master, as follows:

```
commit10 - commit11  <-- master
              |
              \-- commit4 <-- topic/branch2
```

So, I did the following git command:

```
$ git checkout topic/branch2
$ git rebase --onto master topic/branch2
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

And now I cant find commit4... anywhere.

Now the git log int topic/branch2 looks like this:

```
$ git log -n 2
commit2
commit1
```

If I go to the master branch and look 30 entries back in the git log history, I cant find the commit.

Where did my commit4 go? How do I get it back?

Comment: Remember:  rebase overwrites history.  You may be able to track something down in the reflog, but know  that a rebase operation is a potentially dangerous option if great care isn't taken with it.

Comment: @Makoto thanks for the hint about the reflog. This page showed me how to get it back: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html I ended up doing a "git merge <commit4 SHA1>"

Comment: @Makoto if you make a temporary branch before the rebase, it’s not dangerous at all.

Comment: If you look at the reflog you can find the commit id of commit4. Then checkout that commit and create a new branch. Tada! You’ve recovered from a “dangerous” rebase.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's basically what I did. Thanks!

Comment: @Brady fab! Sharing the details in an answer might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Makoto's comment, I was able to solve this by looking in the reflog.

I used this [restoring lost commits](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html) page to restore the commit. Turns out the rebase caused my commit to be treated as a dangling commit.

Luckily I had the SHA1 of the commit4 before I messed things up. So I used the following command to "prove git knew about my dangling commit":

```
$ git fsck --lost-found
<lots of output>
dangling commit 0c990572fd1fd20a5db42141a7a4e0e6e97f6462
<even more output>
```

I was also able to see commit4 in the reflog with this command:

```
$ git reflog
```

And according to the previously mentioned link, you can use either git merge  or git checkout  to recover it. I used merge, since the link said that was quicker.